# VbScript to create logging the activity

Tags: vbscript

With help of some friends I did this code to copy files to different folder based on file extensions. And I am going to schedule to run this script for every ten minutes so whenever it copies a new file it should be logged in text format to drive C. Is it possible? Kindly help me out.

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set testfolder = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
testfolder.CompareMode = vbTextCompare  'case-insensitive
testfolder.Add "env", "D:\env"
testfolder.Add "ikey", "D:\key"
'fso.CreateFolder(testfolder)

CopyFiles fso.GetFolder("D:\source")

Sub CopyFiles(fldr)
 For Each f In fldr.Files
basename  = fso.GetBaseName(f)
extension = fso.GetExtensionName(f)
If testfolder.Exists(extension) Then
dest  = fso.BuildPath(testfolder(extension), f.Name)
If Not fso.FileExists(dest) Then f.Copy dest
End If

Next

For Each sf In fldr.SubFolders
CopyFiles sf
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new object for this and then write to a file.

So, you will need

```
dim fs,fi
Set fs= CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fi=fs.CreateTextFile("testFile.txt",true, -1)
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set testfolder = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

testfolder.CompareMode = vbTextCompare  'case-insensitive
testfolder.Add "env", "D:\env"
testfolder.Add "ikey", "D:\key"
'fso.CreateFolder(testfolder)

CopyFiles fso.GetFolder("D:\source")

Sub CopyFiles(fldr)
   For Each f In fldr.Files
      basename  = fso.GetBaseName(f)
      extension = fso.GetExtensionName(f)

      If testfolder.Exists(extension) Then
         dest  = fso.BuildPath(testfolder(extension), f.Name)
      End If

      If Not fso.FileExists(dest) Then 
         f.Copy dest
         fi.writeline("This file copied") ' THIS IS WHERE THE FAULT IS
      End If
    Next
    For Each sf In fldr.SubFolders
        CopyFiles sf
    Next
    fi.close
    set f=nothing
    set fs=nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: where should i give the path for log if i want to save the log in c:\logs

Comment: @Kumar, do you really want this many logs or to over write the latest. if you're running this every 10 minutes, your log file's  folder will be very big very quickly